# error on duplicate the extension by rename class and files

Tags: module, error, blocks, adminhtml, magento-1

i created extension for custom form which run perfectly but as i need another page with same form i rename all files & classes it gives me error on my error log like.

```
    exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Cusdesign_Block_Adminhtml_Cusdesign' in /home/webfolder/public_html/demo-website/app/Mage.php:595
    Stack trace:
#0 /home/webfolder/public_html/demo-website/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /home/webfolder/public_html/demo-website/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('cusdesign/admin...', Array)
#2 /home/webfolder/public_html/demo-website/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('cusdesign/admin...', 'cusdesign')
#3 /home/webfolder/public_html/demo-website/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('cusdesign/admin...', 'cusdesign')
#4 /home/webfolder/public_html/demo-website/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/webfolder/public_html/demo-website/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/webfolder/public_html/demo-website/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /home/webfolder/public_html/demo-website/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /home/webfolder/public_html/demo-website/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#9 /home/webfolder/public_html/demo-website/app/code/local/M3/Cusdesign/controllers/Adminhtml/CusdesignController.php(7): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#10 /home/webfolder/public_html/demo-website/app/code/local/M3/Cusdesign/controllers/Adminhtml/CusdesignController.php(15): M3_Cusdesign_Adminhtml_CusdesignController->_initAction()
#11 /home/webfolder/public_html/demo-website/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): M3_Cusdesign_Adminhtml_CusdesignController->indexAction()
#12 /home/webfolder/public_html/demo-website/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#13 /home/webfolder/public_html/demo-website/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 /home/webfolder/public_html/demo-website/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 /home/webfolder/public_html/demo-website/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 /home/webfolder/public_html/demo-website/index.php(73): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

used the block class ..

```
class M3_Cusdesign_Block_Cusdesign extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
```

in config file

```
 <blocks>
        <cusdesign>
            <class>M3_Cusdesign_Block</class>
        </cusdesign>
    </blocks>
```

my layout file

```
 <cusdesign_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="cusdesign/cusdesign" name="cusdesign" template="cusdesign/cusdesign.phtml" />
    </reference>
</cusdesign_index_index>
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento is looking for the following class and can't find it:

```
M3_Cusdesign_Block_Adminhtml_Cusdesign
```

Possible reasons:

- the class is not in the right folder or the folder contains a typo it should be under `app/code/<codePool>/M3/Cusdesign/Adminhtml/Cusdesign.php`
- the class name is wrong or contains a typo, it should be `M3_Cusdesign_Block_Adminhtml_Cusdesign`

Comment: my class is located  app/code/local/M3/Cusdesign/Block/Adminhtml/Cusdesign.php with class name M3_Cusdesign_Block_Adminhtml_Cusdesign